# how to edit shopify fulfillment using python api

Tags: python, api, shopify

how to add tracking number and tracking url in existing shopify fulfillment using shopify python api.

code:

```
token = <token>
session = shopify.Session("<shop-name>.myshopify.com", token)
shopify.ShopifyResource.activate_session(session)
a = shopify.Fulfillment.find(2642971265,order_id = 3386372225)
a.tracking_url = "www.example.com/trackingid=123"
a.tracking_number = "1234"
shopify.Fulfillment.save(a)
```

after that it return true but changes are not reflecting anywhere

Answer (score 2):

I forgot to add the other details i.e tracking_urls and tracking_numbers

```
a = shopify.Fulfillment.find(order_id = 3386116225)[0]
a.tracking_company = "pickrr"
a.tracking_number = '12345678'
l = []
l.append('12345678')
a.tracking_numbers = l
a.tracking_url = "pickrr.com/12345678"
l = []
l.append("pickrr.com/12345678")
a.tracking_urls = l
shopify.Fulfillment.save(a)
```

Now everything working fine